# What will be equivalent Struts2 code for the following select tag code in Struts1

Tags: struts2, struts-1, struts-tags

I am new to Struts. I have to migrate code form Struts1 to Struts2 but confused in select tag of Struts2. Please help in writing the equivalent code in Struts2.

```xml
<nested:select property="pmt_type0" onchange="openTable(this,0)">
    <html:option value=""></html:option>
    <html:optionsCollection name="paymentTypesList" label="paymentTypeDescription" value="paymentTypeCode"/>
</nested:select>
```

Comment: please click on [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30455067/edit) and edit your question and its title to refer to `struts` not `struct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```jsp
<s:select name="pmt_type0" 
          list="paymentTypesList"
          listKey="paymentTypeCode" 
          listValue="paymentTypeDescription" 
          emptyOption="true" 
          onchange="openTable(this,0)" />
```

Where `paymentTypesList` is a list of objects with `paymentTypeCode` and `paymentTypeDescription` properties.

To find out more take a look at the [Struts2 tags](https://struts.apache.org/docs/tag-reference.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. HTML , which is generated, is not right. I will update about result later.

Comment: its not generating select tag. I tried simple user defined select tag, still select tag is not getting generated

Comment: no, there are no errors. Its not generating, neither select tag nor textfield. Some weird problem

Comment: @user2332505: Have you configured filter in web.xml? Declared S2 taglib in jsp? BTW you question was about select tag and now turns out that none of S2 tags work.

Comment: yeah all is working fine, only problem is with select and one textfield . Some kind of bug. Working on it

Comment: update :- I am sending List from action class as request().setAttribute("paymentTypesList", newList);

Comment: @user2332505: Don't. Create action property with getter/setter and populate it on action execution or in preparable method.

Comment: Thank you. With setter and getter , its working fine